# Setting the value of a variable in Visual BASIC

Tags: vb.net

Hi i'm new in programming world and I've started my programming by Visual BASIC. I'm trying to set a value of a variable through the program closing event and load the same value in program load event. As example:
At first I tried:

```
Dim Age as Integer
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
Age = 50
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
Textbox1.text = Age
End Sub
```

But when I close the program and restart it, it resets to zero.
Next I tried "Settings" from properties but if I move my program from one location to another then it also resets everything.
Finally I tried Stream readers and writers to catch the final value but for this I had to attach some text files to the programs which I don't want. Can anyone help me how to solve the following problem with custom class libraries or by something else?

Comment: Ending your application and restarting it will reset all your runtime variables. Your options are to store it externally like a text file (which you didn't want), or more commonly, a database. If you won't be restarting your application frequently and just want to store it through the lifespan of the application, you can look into [Application State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94xkskdf.aspx), or simply use [Sessions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87069683(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

All the variables that you have are run time variables. What that means is it will only have value till your program is running.

If you want to store the data taken from user, you store it in database. You can use any kind of database and connect it to your program, store everything in there. You can also retrieve the values from database to use in system when you restart your program.

If you are new to programming and trying to learn visual basic, start with basic concepts or pick up a book that start with basics. Once you know the basics of programming, you can read about connecting program to database.

Answer (score 0):

The value of age is never going to remain static when the application is shut down unless you keep it in the application settings or some sort of flat file, database etc. The initial value could be set in the application when the form opens or from at static value in application settings, but unless you store the value somewhere other than memory, it will not persist.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a form called module1.vb . in this form declare and set your variables . . .

Example

```
Public Age As Integer = 50
```